# Jquery script in Django project isn't detecting form submission

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django, ajax

I'm creating a website using Django, and using Ajax to prevent site reload after submitting a form. Right now, I have orders being displayed on the site with an x button beside each order. Clicking the x cancels the order on the database (a post request that changes a value rather than simply deleting it) and also reloads the div in which the orders are housed. I have other forms on this website that are working correctly (they do have fields, though and use crispyforms). **The problem I'm facing is that the script isn't detecting that the form is submitted.**

Here are the pertinent parts of my project:

**views.py**

```
class CancelForm(ModelForm):
 class Meta:
    model = Order
    fields = ['Filled']
...
def cancelorder(request, pk):
    form = CancelForm(request.POST)
    if request.is_ajax and request.method == "POST":
        order = Order.objects.get(pk=pk)
        order.Filled = "C"
        instance = order.save(update_fields=["Filled"])
        return JsonResponse({"canceled": pk}, status=200)
    return JsonResponse({"error": ""}, status=400)
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.orderpage, name="order-index"),
    path('cancel_order/<int:pk>/', views.cancelorder, name="cancel_order"),
    path('post/ajax/order/', views.postorder, name = "post_order"),
    path('yourorders/', views.yourorders, name="your_orders"),
    path('allorders/', views.allorders, name="all_orders"),
]
```

**orderpage.html** (this is my main page, with the div that is to be reloaded on yourorders.html)

```
<div class="container-fluid ActiveOrderInfoDiv" id="YourOrdersDiv">
  {% include 'order/yourorders.html' %}
</div>
```

**yourorders.html**

```
{% for order in all_orders %}
  <div class="row">
...
    <div class="col">{{ order.OrderID }}</div>
    <form action="{% url 'order:cancel_order' pk=order.OrderID %}" id="cancel_button" method="POST">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <button type="submit" class="close" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
    </form>
  </div>
  {% endfor %}
```

**Javascript (here, check 2 is never logged)**

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
      $("#cancel_button").submit(function (e) {
          console.log("check 2");
          e.preventDefault();
          console.log("check 3");
          $.ajax({
            url: "{% url 'order:your_orders' %}",
            success: function (response) {
              $("#YourOrdersDiv").load("/order/yourorders/");
            },
            error: function (response) {
            }
          });
        });
    });
```

**What I've tried**

- Moved the script to **yourorders.html** (I thought maybe the JS wasn't seeing the cancel_button ID)
- Used console.log to see where the flow stopped (it doesn't seem to pick up that the cancel button was submitted)
- Added the CancelForm modelform (previously I was updating the DB without a modelform)
- Generally poking around with Ajax syntax and order
- Looking at other questions here on StackOverflow - I seem to be following them, and my syntax may just be right, it's just not picking up that the cancel_button form is being submitted

Comment: Has the form been reloaded? Binding the event handler will only happen on page load, if the form is reloaded then the new form will not have the event handler bound to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should delegate the event handler to the document level so that when the form is reloaded the event is still handled. When you "reload" the form you are inserting a new element into the DOM that does not have the event handler attached to it

```
$(document).on("submit", "#cancel_button", function(e) {
  ...
```

Comment: It looks like this bypasses the view method. Following the log, I can see that the ajax indeed runs (thus the page isn't reloaded while the divs are), but the cancelorder view does not. Commenting out "e.preventDefault();" allows cancelorder to run (but doesn't prevent reloading the page)

Comment: You need to call the cancel order view in your handler if you want to do everything asynchronously

Comment: Ok, if I understand you correctly you're saying I need to call the url that corresponds to the correct view, from javascript. I've updated my code for yourorders.html above, showing that the url needs an argument from a specific iteration of the for loop (corresponding to that row's primary key). Is there a way to get this in my handler? Thank you for your help.

Comment: You set the correct delete URL in the form's `action` right? You can access this via the event object in your handler `e.target.action`

Comment: Thank you! For anyone else with this problem, I changed 'url: "{% url 'order:your_orders' %}"' into 'url: e.target.action'